# Is $\mathbb{N} \times\mathbb{R}$ closed, open or neither?

Tags: analysis

So I have to prove if is  $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{R}$ closed, open or neither?

Any help?

Comment: Closed or open as a subset of what space? If as a subset of $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ go back to the definitions. Hint: open circles are your friends.

Comment: Openness/closedness is a relative notion, which depends on the choice of ambient space. In one extreme, a topological space $X$ is closed in $X$ itself. If the ambient space is $\mathbb{R}^2$ equipped with the standard topology, then $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{R}$ is closed since it is the product of two closed sets in $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 3):

In what topological space? If $\mathbf{R}^2$, closed. If $\mathbf{R}\times\mathbf{N}$ itself, both. In an arbitrary space $X$, who’s to say?

Answer (score 0):

In the plane $\Bbb R^2$ (with the Euclidean topology, or equivalently, the product topology) this is closed as a (Cartesian) product of the closed sets $\Bbb N$ and $\Bbb R$ of $\Bbb R$. General fact in product spaces.